# Чем отличаются две фразы?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Чем отличается фраза ***"на территории субъекта"*** от ***"в границах территории субъекта"***?

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, второй вариант является тавтологией, поскольку в этом контексте территория и так определяется как участок суши, заданный административными границами; если что-то находится на территории, то оно по определению внутри её границ.

Но такое употребление может быть уместно, если необходимо очень явно, жирной линией подчеркнуть ограниченность чего-либо. Например:

`Полномочия местного самоуправления действуют только в границах территории субъекта.`